# Git and Svn - dcommit has corrupted my code

Tags: git, svn

I tried to commit my git repo on a subversion system and something went wrong. Here in detail what I've done so far:

1. starting from a commit on our svn, I launched this command: 
   `$git svn clone my_repo_url -s`
2. worked on my code (so I've made my stuff);
3. when all was ok I rebased everything. Since I read that svn doesn't work very well with branches;
4. So, with a single branch (master), I ran this command: `git svn dcommit`
5. The push onto svn server failed (probably some conflicts to resolve). I didn't want to solve those at that moment so I launched this command: `git rebase --abort` (maybe I didn't read very well what it does, but git was suggesting this);
6. Right now I have lost my solution (.sln file) and on a project I can see a folder called 'Backup' (with all my classes duplicated)... wtf

The simple question is: what is happening? How can I restore my solution before to the 'git svn dcommit'?

Here the output of my .git/logs/HEAD:

```
5edc59acb6e200aef991d7de124008f8120ee187 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538033064 +0200      commit: Change the Map table label
1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 0d80fd2165866dd809dbdf16287898a71d31fecb my_name my_email 1538059453 +0000      rebase: checkout refs/remotes/git-svn
0d80fd2165866dd809dbdf16287898a71d31fecb 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538059583 +0200      rebase: aborting
1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538059584 +0200      rebase: updating HEAD
1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538059671 +0200      checkout: moving from master to TestMergeSvn_feature
1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 14687b653cd9b13bba47a971af002f95bfac3bf6 my_name my_email 1538059705 +0000      rebase: checkout refs/remotes/git-svn
14687b653cd9b13bba47a971af002f95bfac3bf6 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538060096 +0200      rebase: aborting
1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538060097 +0200      rebase: updating HEAD
1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538060179 +0200      checkout: moving from TestMergeSvn_feature to master
1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 5edc59acb6e200aef991d7de124008f8120ee187 my_name my_email 1538060222 +0200      checkout: moving from master to 5edc59a
5edc59acb6e200aef991d7de124008f8120ee187 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538060314 +0200      checkout: moving from 5edc59acb6e200aef991d7de124008f8120ee187 to master
1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 e009e033a3b1811e01c08f28a0a6cc2fa71fd566 my_name my_email 1538060866 +0200      checkout: moving from master to e009e03
e009e033a3b1811e01c08f28a0a6cc2fa71fd566 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538061011 +0200      checkout: moving from e009e033a3b1811e01c08f28a0a6cc2fa71fd566 to master
1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 1234c77ff6a21551ea615bee11cd9c56f2beb839 my_name my_email 1538061307 +0200      reset: moving to 1234c77
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crossposted [there](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/git-users/RlQw3--jTUI/discussion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might some additional steps that I may be forgetting about but... this is what I would do: `git rebase --abort` if you were in the middle of the rebase. Make sure you are at the revision you first created with your work (don't worry, if it's committed, you won't lose it that easily). If you aren't, go back to it (check git reflog, just in case). Now, do a `git svn fetch` to collect all changes you don't have from svn. Then rebase or cherry-pick changes to the svn branch you want to push to. Then run `git svn dcommit`.

Comment: Honestly I can't perform a 'git svn fetch' right now because I need to be connected to our LAN (and I'm not currently, I'm going to try tomorrow). Anyway if I run a 'git status', it tells me that the working tree is clean as well as I checkout to a previous commit (that's ok, but I still miss some files like the .sln)...

Comment: Try checking out to the revision where you actually committed it. check `git reflog`.

Comment: Hi, I launched the command 'git svn rebase' and now it's trying to merge my work for every commit (42 in total). Right now, for every one of them it's asking me to merge manullay some files... Seriously, I can't do that 42 times.

Comment: I suppose that the 'git reset --skip' is the only solution to get all working fine fastly.

Comment: The way I turn X git revisions into a single svn commit is by merging (--no-ff, if needed), then dcommitting. When the revision is created when dcomitting, git will save that revision as a merge commit connected to the original revisions on git.... on svn it will all look like a single commit on the branch history.

Comment: I have finished my squashing into a single commit: not trivial for sure, because I had to merge manually many files. Not sure why that's happened since I had a single branch (from a multiple 'git rebase my_branch' done before). 
Anyway, after this operation, the 'git svn dcommit' went smoothly.